# How to emitVerilog from Firrtl with annotations

Tags: annotations, verilog, chisel, firrtl

I am new to Chisel/Firrtl but I find it very interesting!
I am looking for an example of how to take some annotation (like for example one-hot signal) from chisel3 through firrtl onto Verilog where it could be added as a comment.